# How to merge values of collection using pluck function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use the `pluck()` function to get output collection with key, value:

```
$work_types = Work::orderBy('name')->get()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Output is:

```
{
  0 => "Name1",
  1 => "Name2",
  2 => "Name3
}
```

How can I merge value `name` with value `id` that to get the following object:

```
 {
      0 => "0 -Name1",
      1 => "1 - Name2",
      2 => "2 - Name3
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) function with [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions) fuction to this as:

```
$work_types = Work::select('id', DB::raw("concat(id, ' - ',name) as id_name"))
                ->orderBy('name')
                ->pluck('id_name', 'id')
```

You don't need to get all the columns and then do pluck. You can directly pluck from the database.

Answer (score 6):

The Laravel way is to [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getIdNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->id.' - '.$this->name;
}
```

And then use it:

```
$work_types = Work::orderBy('name')->pluck('id_name', 'id');
```

Comment: I needed to `get()` before I used `pluck()` but this is the best answer for me. Also, `$value` is redundant here, you can just use blank parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map`:

```
$work_types = Work::orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'id')
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return "$key - $item";
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Merge ****FirstName** and **LastName**** From Database:

```
'clients' => Client::select('id', DB::raw("concat(first_name, '   ',last_name) as f_l"))

                ->orderBy('id','desc')

                ->pluck('f_l', 'id')

                ->prepend('Select Clients.....',''),
```